# Inject HTML code to a block using modules only

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to inject an HTML code to a block without using modules only? Without the need to copy anything to the `./app/design/` directory? Or is it actually a normal practice for Magento 1.9 modules to also place files in the `./app/design/` directory?

Comment: did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also add custom code/files using layout XML in your theme.

A simple example would be if in `[magento-root]/app/design/[package]/[theme]/layout/local.xml`, you added:

```
<default>
    <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="some.name" template="path/to/example.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

Any code you then put in `[magento-root]/app/design/[package]/[theme]/template/path/to/example.phtml` would be added to every page (the `<default>` handle) and it would be placed near the end of the main content (the `<reference name="content">` tag).

It takes a while to learn a quick way to find the specific block that you want to add to and place your code in a specific place, but you can use this to add custom content without copying files to your theme.

A good place to start in locating the files is in `Admin->System->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Debug->Template Path Hints`.  Note:  **This can only be enabled at the website/Store View scope-level**

That would give you the path for the .phtml file, then you can search for that filepath in any file under `app/design/frontend/*/*/layout/` to find the name of the block/other details.  For more information on layout XML, [Magento DevDocs Pt 4](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add scripts such as google tag manager that are to be added directly in the head and included in every page in `System->Configuration->Design->Head` in admin , but for more specific tasks than that you will have to work with your theme files.

And yes, it is normal practice to do so.